# a positive word for "to play with something" in a passionate but unprofessional way

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, personality

"She loves to ... with her computer all day."

I found *to tinker with* and *to fiddle with*" but they seem to have a rather negative meaning.

I want to express that the person occupies herself with something that she has a passion for but in an informal or unprofessional way. If there is no other word, could I use tinker and/or fiddle without a native speaker having a negative impression?

Update: Playing in the sense of physically playing with the *internals* of a machine etc.

Comment: "play" possibly remain your best option; there are other words that are probably overly formal - experiment, engage, interact, explore, practise, immerse (herself in).

Comment: @Nothingatall In that case, _tinker_ would actually fit the context best. If you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Suzana_K- I ***think*** Nothing at all meant that **"tinkering with her computer*** implies opening the box, checking the wiring, making sure the RAM chips are seated correctly in the motherboard, checking the screws supporting the graphics card, and so forth; in other words, ***physically tinkering.*** "Play" would be the correct word for what I think you mean.

Comment: No, I really understood the meaning well and "physically tinkering" was exactly what I wanted to express. Sorry if my question was unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you said tinker, it would mean she was opening the box, checking the things to see how they work, perhaps repairing them. It's not a particularly negative word.

Answer (score -1):

You might try an action word such as *fly*, *dream*, *sail*, *explore*, *escape*, *enchant*, *tickle*, *dazzle*, or *adventure*.